# Select With a String Value Return

Tags: c#, string, select, return

I Have an application C#  that connect and do some thing in a database, so i need to find a serial number in a table and return it, I do that but i have a problem :

```
public int Select_Begin(string serial)
{
   string query = "SELECT serial FROM `compteur_mono` WHERE   serial = " + serial + ";";
   //Open connection
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
   if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
   {
      int numero = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      return numero;
   }
   else
   {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

When i execute that the result is -1 always But when i do that :

```
public string Select_Begin(string serial)
{
   string query = "SELECT serial FROM `compteur_mono` WHERE   serial = " + serial + ";";
   //Open connection
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
   if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
   {
       string serial = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       return serial;
   }
   else
   {
      return null;
   }
}
```

This Error Appear : Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Some Help Please, I wont use a dataReader because i Have only one serial to return it :*
Thanks

Comment: Don't use a global connection, it's normally better to create the connection in the method where you use it, best with the `using` statement to ensure that it get's closed properly. You don't need to be afraid that it's less efficient. The opposite is true with connection-pooling (default).

Comment: Can my serial be `x'; DROP TABLE compteur_mono; --` ??

Comment: Even if not today maybe tomorrow if developer 2 thinks that the method is useful. So never concatenate strings but use sql-parameters.

Comment: Te other fun question: is `serial` unique in the table? Can there be more than one match?

Comment: It's also not clear what you expect from the method. Do you want to check if that serial already exists in the table? Then either use `SELECT COUNT(*)....` and `ExecuteScalar` or `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS... THEN 1 ELSE 0` which is more efficient if the table is large.

Comment: @TimSchmelter depending on how the server is configured, it could also be for combined check and case correction; if this was SQL Server, I would probably add "TOP 1" - not sure if the syntax is the same in mysql

Answer (score 8):

`ExecuteNonQuery` **does not expect a query**. `SELECT serial` is a query. Change that to `ExecuteScalar` and all will work. You should add some `using` statements and parameterize if possible, note.

```
const string query =
    "SELECT serial FROM `compteur_mono` WHERE serial = @serial;";

using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial", serial);
    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        return (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return null;
}
```

or with "dapper":

```
return connection.Query<string>(
    "SELECT serial FROM `compteur_mono` WHERE serial = @serial;",
    new { serial }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hi Marc, Thanks for Answer I Have an error on executeScalar()

 Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @user3645814 if you look in the above, I edited in that cast 38 minutes ago